# Creating BMP Imagery within DLL

Tags: c#, image, dll

I need to create a very simple graph in C#. The code to do so is pretty straight forward when you are painting the image onto a form, but I'm finding it tricky to figure out how I can do so from within my DLL.

Ideally I'd like to use the System.Drawing namespace and the Graphics class since it's pretty easy, but I suspect I can't natively play with System.Drawing from a C# DLL.

Suggestions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Just create an Image? Or are you attempting to draw on a form or something?

Comment: "but I suspect I can't natively play with System.Drawing from a C# DLL."  Your supicions are incorrect....try it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!  You can create your code in a DLL just like you would in an EXE.  You can reference System.Windows.Forms if you want and launch forms from within a dll.  It's all dependent on which resources you reference.

If you have created your code in a forms project, you can easily move it to a library project.  The best approach would to be to create a custom user control that would do this.  There are lots of tutorials that will show you have that is done.

Here's an example of a custom control in a DLL:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step

Answer (score 0):

I am using System.Drawing in a DLL and works just fine.

I use it to draw a custom graph and save the result to a jpg graphics

Comment: Darn it, you know, once you think you cover every base. Yeah, I did try to include/using System.Drawing, but I forgot to add the reference to my DLL. I suspect that will do the trick, I'll loop back shortly and close the question (I suspect it will work just fine).

Comment: In something like program coding you never finish learning :)